# Vnc windows 10 login stuck

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, remote-desktop, vnc, tightvnc

Hi i am running Tight VNC server on a remote win 10 PC which has 2 monitors.

When i log in with a VNC viewer, it prompts me for a password and i am presented with the Windows 10 lock screen, everything normal.

When i hit enter to type my windows password the screen goes black. The cursor then appears to be stuck in the center of the screen.

If i type my password anyway and hit enter nothing happens. After some time the lock screen returns or if i reconnect.

The target machine has two displays but i am only presented with the 1080p res of the secondary monitor.

Does anyone know some way around this windows + VNC login problem, without access to the target machine? I have tried different VNC clients and none of them show both monitors or make the password field visible, just a black screen after the initial win 10 lock screen. Ultra vnc viewer the screen flashes grey and white after hitting enter.

Comment: So I just have an opinion or two and no answer.  You don't tell us what your client is.  If your client is Windows, why on earth would you use VNC instead of RDC?  I have indeed (in the past) used VNC windows-to-windows.. but it is because I needed access to things blocked out by RDC like screen resolution.  Not because it was a better way to access my remote desktop.

Comment: hey its a windows 10 machine running tight vnc server. yeah rdc probbaly a good shout for future. would be good to find out if this can be worked around in the meantime though

Comment: windows 10 client pc yes